# converting m,n dataframe to x,x dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a data frame as shown below .it is 9,3 dataframe with the values.

```
col1 col2 val
a   b     15
a   c     19
a   a     20
b   a     15
b   b     55 
b   c     16
c   a     19
c   b     16
c   c     5
```

i want some thing 3,3 dataframe.

```
  a   b   c
a 20  15   19
b  .   .   .
c  .    .    .
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read about [pandas.DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). You can use it like this: `df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2', values='val')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). For more clarification beyond the pandas docs, I really enjoyed this blog post titled [Reshaping in Pandas - Pivot, Pivot-Table, Stack and Unstack explained with Pictures](http://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/)

```
>>> data
[['a', 'b', 15], ['a', 'c', 19], ['a', 'a', 20], ['b', 'a', 15], ['b', 'b', 
55], ['b', 'c', 16], ['c', 'a', 19], ['c', 'b', 16], ['c', 'c', 5]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'val'])
>>> df
  col1 col2  val
0    a    b   15
1    a    c   19
2    a    a   20
3    b    a   15
4    b    b   55
5    b    c   16
6    c    a   19
7    c    b   16
8    c    c    5
>>> df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2',  values='val')
col2   a   b   c
col1
a     20  15  19
b     15  55  16
c     19  16   5
```